# SQL nested query with count and partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle database and have following table:

```
ID  SYSTEM_NAME INTERFACE_NAME  TIMEIN              REQUEST         ORDER_ID    TARGET_SYSTEM_NAME  TARGET_INTERFACE_NAME   MSISDN  HOST    SOURCE
11  Logical     AddProduct      02/11/2015 08:35:00 This is request 0           RFCO                 XXX                    Host
```

I want to select max request count in a hour per day.Like max request in which hour of day and that hour and for last 15 day.

I am using this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT count(*) as max_hour ,to_char(timein,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as date_hour 
FROM LOG_REQUEST PARTITION(req_2015_02_24)
where SYSTEM_NAME='Logical'
and INTERFACE_NAME='AddProduct'
--and trunc(timein)>= trunc(SYSDATE-15)
GROUP BY to_char(timein,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24')
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
)  where rownum =1;
```

Because I am using partition for 1 day (date) it is giving me max number of request in a hour of a day with single date but i want this for last 4 or five dates.

Just like:

```
Max_Request_in_Hour Hour Date 
89                  21   02/02/2015
99                  9    03/02/2015
29                  8    04/02/2015
```

Can any sql expert help me on this.

Comment: Why not move the ORDER BY max_hour to the outer/main query?

Comment: Actually query is giving me correct result for one date like for 02/02/2015 but i want result for more then one date like 02/02/2015, 03/02/2015, 04/02/2015 for every date

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT proc_date, max(cnt_hour) as max_hour, max(date_hour) keep (dense_rank first order by cnt_hour desc) as date_hour
  FROM (
SELECT count(*) as cnt_hour ,to_char(timein,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as date_hour, trunc(timein) as proc_date
 FROM LOG_REQUEST PARTITION(req_2015_02_24)
 where SYSTEM_NAME='Logical'
  and INTERFACE_NAME='AddProduct'
--and trunc(timein)>= trunc(SYSDATE-15)
GROUP BY to_char(timein,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24'), trunc(timein)
)
group by proc_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Rusty your efforts are good but my requirements are different let put it this way i don't want to use partition or i want to use partition but more then one and in result i want individual row( hour and count) for very partition. hope you understand.